# Fourier transform

Tags: reference-request, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Suppose $1< p<\infty$. Let $f$ be a continuous function with compact support defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Does it exist a function $g \in L^p(\mathbb{T})$ such that: 
$$
\widehat{f}|_{\mathbb{Z}}=\widehat{g}
$$ 
where $\widehat{f}$ denote the Fourier transform on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\widehat{g}$ the Fourier transform on $\mathbb{T}$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking
$$
g(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(x+2\pi n)
$$
will give the desired result since $g\in C(\mathbb{T})$.

Comment: Thank you very much. A last question: do you think that the answer to the question is yes for abitrary abelian locally compact groups $G$ and $H$ such that $H\subset \widehat{G}$ instead of the groups $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Zouba There is a canonical projection $P:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{T}\ $ here and $g(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{y=P^{-1}(x)}f(y)\ $. In the general case I don't know. Perhaps if one is a covering space for another this reasoning still will be correct.